# Union e order by juntos

Tags: php, mysql

Bom tenho no banco de dados MYSQL a tabela chatlogs com: de,para,msg,datetime.

Onde ficam as mensagem trocadas e informações ok, partindo deste ponto gostaria de saber como faria para fazer um histórico das mensagens, exemplo:

> o usuário carlos entrou na conta dele no chat de maria entao recuperaria as conversas antigas novamente em ordem por datahr utilizando o datetime

Ex:

```
select msg from chatlogs where de = joana and para = carlos order by datetime ... conseguiria recuperar o historico msgs dela em ordem ... porem preciso que o histórico mostre tudo em ordem minhas msg tambem ...
```

Ex:

> joana:oi
>   carlos: oie td bem?
>   joana: sim e vc?
>   carlos: td ok

de ordem correta + não sei como faria, havia tentado assim:

```
select msg from chatlogs where de = joana and para = carlos 
union
select msg from chatlogs where de = carlos and para = joana 
order by datetime
```

Explicação do que tentei fazer:
tentei pegar todas msg enviada de carlos para joana e todas msg de joana para carlos e juntei com union tudo e depois mandei receber em ordem por datahr.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Apesar de eu preferir a solução do @ThiagoThaison abaixo, o que você tem devia funcionar. Qual problema deu?

Comment: opa obrigado a atenção bfavaretto , então é porque estou sem poder testar agora e como havia precisado e um rapaz disse que daquela maneira não daria certo vim achar uma solução , sempre é bom sobrar doq faltar kkkkk

Answer (score 2):

Você pode ter esse resultado simplesmente alterando seu select sem a necessidade de utilizar o `union`.

```
select msg from chatlogs where (de = joana and para = carlos) or (de = carlos and para = joana) order by datetime
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado cara, um abraço!.